# Undo changes is not working, either on Visual Studio or SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Each time I'm trying to switch branches, but I'm getting the usual error that I need to commit/slash first my changes before doing so. The branch I'm in is the *dev*, so I don't think I made any changes there. Anyway, I only commit to my own branch the create a pull request.

1. I've tried to undo the changes by right clicking the file, then select *undo changes*
2. Discard on **sourcetree**
3. I've tried `git checkout .`
4. I've done what it's recommended in this [post](https://elanderson.net/2016/11/visual-studio-2015-team-explorer-fails-to-undo-changes-using-git/)
5. I close Visual Studio, delete the local folder, delete the tab on *SourceTree*, the re-clone the *dev* clone.

Each time I open SourceTree and/or Visual Studio, I still see that file appSettings.test.json, that I didn't changes, complaining about changes that I need to commit.

I want to have a clean dev on my local.

Thanks for helping

Comment: if discard didnt work. Try setting up the same repo in a different folder. Otherwise, enable hidden files, go into the .git-folder and remove the logs.

Answer (score 9):

Stash the changes you want to remove and then drop the stash.

Answer (score 0):

Stage the changes you want to remove, and they will just disappear.

(However VS got confused, it wouldn't let me stash them, but attempting a stage fixed it)